# vc6 to vs2010 porting error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-6

i am stuck in a porting of my project from VC6 to VS2010. Please can any one help me out.

```
void CEdchLoop::ReceiveSdu(UINT8* Sdu, UINT32 BitLength, int Fn)
{
UINT8* pPdu   = Sdu;
    int Bit       = 8;

    UINT32 SourceId    = GetBitsL(pPdu, BitLength, Bit, 32);
    UINT32 PduUniqueId = GetBitsL(pPdu, BitLength, Bit, 32);       
}
```

in the above code i get error as error C2664: 'GetBitsL' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'UINT8 *' to 'const UINT8 *&'

and GetBitsL is defined as `UINT32 GetBitsL(const UINT8*& Bin, UINT32& BitLength, int& Bit, int Count)`

Please can any one help me with this. i am sorry if its not a brilliant question. But to be fool for five minutes is better than being a fool forever.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`GetBitsL` requires a reference to a pointer-to-const-UINT8. You're giving it a reference to a pointer-to-volatile-UINT8, and there is no direct by-reference translation. Change `pPdu` to be that by:

```
// UINT8* pPdu   = Sdu;
const UINT8* pPdu(Sdu);
```

It is still initialized to point the same `UINT8` as `Sdu`, but now as a pointer-to-const-UINT8 which the function expects. The function can still modify the *pointer*, but not what it *points to*. (which should be a hint that you might not be using the function as design-intended, so consider that).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is best explained with a demonstration:

```
int * ip;
const int *& cipr = ip;
```

Okay, at this point, `cipr` is a reference to `ip`.  This is not legal, you'll see why in the following sections.

```
const int * cip = some_const_data;
cipr = cip;
```

That assignment was legal, because, being a (reference to) a pointer to const data, `cipr` is allowed to be assigned to point to const data.  But because of that, since `cipr` is a reference to `ip`, now `ip` points to const data.  That's a problem:

```
*ip = 7;
```

This is legal, because the type of `ip` is pointer to non-const int.  However, through some trickery above, we made it point to const data.  That cannot be allowed, and so our initial statement, where we bound `cipr` to refer to `ip` must be illegal.  And that's the same thing you are trying to do by passing `pPdu` to `GetBitsL`.